# Switching module variables to instance variables

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, constructor

I made a module to for concurrent async/await function processing similar to npm module `'async'`, only without callbacks.

I got it working as far as:

```
module.exports = function () {
  module.internalQueue = []
  module.func = undefined
  module.parallelism =  1

  const process = async () => {
      const pickUpNextTask = () => {
        if (module.internalQueue.length) {
          return module.func(module.internalQueue.shift())
        }
      }
      const startChain = () => {
        return Promise.resolve().then(function next() {
          return pickUpNextTask().then(next)
        })
      }
      let chains = []
      for (let k = 0; k < module.parallelism; k += 1) {
        chains.push(startChain());
      }
      await Promise.all(chains)
      module.drain()
  }

  module.queue = (func, parallelism = 1) => {
    module.func = func
    module.parallelism = parallelism
    return module
  }

  module.push = async (customers) => {
    module.internalQueue.push(customers)
    await process()
  }

  module.drain = () => {}

  return module
}
```

I believe that my solution will work when there is only one queue. If there are multiple queues, races will kill the code.

I am trying to refactor this as an object:

```
class async extends Object {
  constructor() {
    this.internalQueue = []
    this.propertyIsEnumerable = 1
    this.func = undefined
    this.drain = () => {}
  }

  static queue(func, parallelism = 1) {
    const o = new async.constructor()
    o.func = func
    o.parallelism = parallelism
    return o
  }

  async push(q) {
    this.internalQueue.push(q)
    await process()
  }

  async process() {
    const pickUpNextTask = () => {
      if (this.internalQueue.length) {
        return this.func(this.internalQueue.shift())
      }
    }
    const startChain = () => {
      return Promise.resolve().then(function next() {
        return pickUpNextTask().then(next)
      })
    }
    let chains = []
    for (let k = 0; k < this.parallelism; k += 1) {
      chains.push(startChain());
    }
    await Promise.all(chains)
    this.drain()
  }
}
```

Is it possible to have a static method that would call the constructor and return the object? If yes, please share pointers.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Don't make it more complicated than it needs to be. Just keep the values in local variables instead of putting them on `module`. You don't need a `class` for that.

```
module.exports = function queue(func, parallelism = 1) {
  var internalQueue = []

  async function process() {
    function pickUpNextTask() {
      if (internalQueue.length) {
        return func(internalQueue.shift())
      }
    }
    async function startChain() {
      while (true) // I don't think this is what you want
        await pickUpNextTask();
    }
    let chains = []
    for (let k = 0; k < parallelism; k += 1) {
      chains.push(startChain());
    }
    await Promise.all(chains)
    drain()
  }
  function drain() {}

  return async function push(customers) {
    internalQueue.push(customers)
    await process() // I don't think this is what you want
  }
}
```

Comment: in your example, `push` won't work like I need to though.
if one changes your solution with:
```
  module.push = async function (customers) {
    internalQueue.push(customers)
    await process() // I don't think this is what you want
  }

  return module
```

Again, we have `push()` working, but the queue is shared.

Comment: BTW, @Bergi - thank you very much for your suggestions.

Comment: @MosheShmukler Maybe you want to do `return {push: async function() {…}};`? Don't use `module`, create your own object with the things that you want to expose.